# Distortion in webpage due to change in DPI in Windows settings in Chromium

Tags: winforms, chromium, cefsharp

Running the CefSharp/WinForms/MinimalExample on Win 10 machine with display setting set to 125% causes a weird distortion in the website as I hover my mouse over the DOM element.

Here is how it looks,

[image]

As you can see, as I hover over the address text box, the text box jumps. I tried to then switch to html5test.com and it still has the same issue.

This only occurs when the display setting is set to anything other than 100%. Is this a bug, or I need to change something?

Comment: That screen shot isn't of the official `CefSharp` projects. There are some hoops to jump through to get `High Dpi` working, search the `GitHub` project.

Comment: It is the demo CefSharp project in the Quick Start, https://github.com/OceanAirdrop/WinFormsHTMLChromium/

Is there a sample `GitHub` project you can suggest for `High Dpi`?

Comment: @amaitland I found this, https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/738. Is there something similar for WinForms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so it is really simple. It has nothing to do with `CefSharp` but you need to make your `WinForm DPIAware` and the easiest way to do that is,

1. Right-Click on your project and select Add -> New Item
2. Select `Application Manifest File`
3. If you are using VS 2015, search for `dpiaware` term. Uncomment the code and rebuild and you are set.

In case, you don't have VS 2015, copy this code,

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
```

and paste it inside the `<assembly>` tag. Save and rebuild and your WinForm is DPI Aware.